# Removing Global.asax still executing code

Tags: c#, web, seo

I am running an asp.net web application and, for search engine optimisation, would like any domain name that I have bought to 301 redirect to my preferred domain name.

For testing purposes I added a Global.asax page to my localhost project and added the following code:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
  if(!currentUrl.StartsWith("http://www.mydomain.org")) 
  { 
    string strStart = currentUrl.Substring(0, currentUrl.indexOf(@"/Pages"));
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"; 
    Response.AddHeader("Location", currentUrl.Replace(strStart, "http://www.mydomain.org")); 
    Response.End(); 
  } 
}
```

I replaced the "http://www.mydomain.org" with one of my current domain names.  It all ran as I wanted it to.  However, now when I remove that code from the .asax file, or even remove the asax file completely, that snippet of code still runs.  So effectively running my localhost project opens my online website and I cannot stop this behaviour.

I have done the following:

- Deleted EVERYTHING in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder
- Deleted the .dlls in my /bin folder and the entire /obj folder
- Cleaned and rebuilt my solution.
- Created an entirely new solution, then added files to it.  This works at first but with the addition of the Global.asax file the same behaviour occurs.

Although this is the behaviour I eventually want, I would like to run, debug and edit it after my first implementation of it. I have seen the same problem before but it was seemingly fixed by one of the above methods.  Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to attach the debugger to the IIS process worker instance to see what code is being executed?

Comment: @Penfold I am not quite sure how to do that. am debugging then clicking "attach to process" in the debug menu and clicking on the firefox process for my website.  seems to be doing nothing.  not done this before so not sure I am doing it right.

Comment: No you need to attach to the IIS process where you code is being exectuted.  The process will be called w3wp.exe, there may be more than one if you are running many sites on the same server.

Comment: @Penfold - ok so by doing the same thing (Debug -> Attach to Process) there is no file there called w3wp.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with your code. It is caching of the 301 you are struggling with.

Caching of 301 can happen in many places along the way your request is going through, starting form your browser and the behavior can become unpredictable because of this

Comment: ahaha that is hilarious! so simple! wasn't aware that f5 would not clear that cache. been driving me crazy. thank you

Comment: just to clarify i manually removed firefox's cache by going to Options -> Network -> Cached Web Content and clicking "Clear Now"